# Correctly Call __set__ in MongoEngine Document constructor

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, numpy, mongoengine

I'm intending to store Pandas DataFrames in MongoDB using the Python [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/) framework; coercing Pandas Dataframes to a Python Dict via `df.to_list()` and storing them as a nested Document attribute.   I'm attempting to minimize the amount of code I have to write to make the round trip from Pandas DataFrame to BSON and back by using a custom field type called `DataFrameField` which is [defined in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jdthorpe/93145e8093258a3b73b2bd458533176d) that coerces the pandas data frame to a python dict and back within the `__set__` and `__get__` methods.

This works great when setting the DataFrameField using dot notation, as in:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mongoengine import *

a_pandas_data_frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'goods': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'stock': [5, 10, 30, 40, 10],
    'category': ['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1'],
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-01-06', '2014-02-09', '2014-03-09'])
})

class my_data(Document):
        data_frame = DataFrameField() # defined in the referenced gist

foo = my_data()
foo.data_frame = a_pandas_data_frame
```

but if I pass `a_pandas_data_frame` it to the constructor, I get:

```
>>> bar = my_data(data_frame = a_pandas_data_frame)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MPGWRK-006\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 116, in __init__
    setattr(self, key, value)
  File "C:\Users\MPGWRK-006\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 186, in __setattr__
    super(BaseDocument, self).__setattr__(name, value)
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in __set__
ValueError: value is not a pandas.DataFrame instance
```

If i add a print statement like `print value` to the `__set__` method, and call the constructor, it prints:

```
['category', 'date', 'goods', 'stock']
```

which is the list of column names of the data frame (i.e. `list(a_pandas_data_frame.columns)`).  Is there any way to prevent the MongoEngine Document Constructor from passing something other than the object passed on to the `__set__` method?

Thanks!

PS, I also asked this question at the [MongoEngine Repo] (https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1597) but there are about 300 open issues, so I'm not sure I expect a response on that forum any time soon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through the source it appears you need to define `to_python` method on your `DataFrameField` field, else it will fall back to `mongoengine.fields.DictField`'s `to_python` method.

`mongoengine.fields.DictField`'s `to_python` method is basically `ComplexBaseField`'s [`to_python` method](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/base/fields.py#L306). This method on receiving a `DataFrame` decides that the object is [sort of a list](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/base/fields.py#L318) and [returns the values](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/base/fields.py#L342) obtained from enumerating `DataFrame` instance.

And here is the part that calls [`to_python` on the field object](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/base/document.py#L111).

```
if key in self._fields or key in ('id', 'pk', '_cls'):
    if __auto_convert and value is not None:
        field = self._fields.get(key)
        if field and not isinstance(field, FileField):
            value = field.to_python(value)
```

Hence, in your case you could simply define it as:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    return value
```